# Why is the size of this set 1 after adding 5 objects?

Tags: java, hashmap, hashset

I'm trying to figure out why this code outputs 1:

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<Foo> myFooSet= new HashSet<Foo>(); 
        myFooSet.add(new Foo(2));
        myFooSet.add(new Foo(1));
        myFooSet.add(new Foo(3));
        myFooSet.add(new Foo(3));
        myFooSet.add(new Foo(2));
        System.out.print(myFooSet.size());
    }
}
class Foo {
     Integer code;
     Foo(Integer c) {
         code= c;
     }
     public boolean equals(Foo f) {
         return false;
     }
     public boolean equals(Object f) {
         return true;
     }
     public int hashCode() {
         return 17;
     }
}
```

Comment: Because the hashcode is the same and equals returns true so all 5 elemens are considered equal and replace each other (as you surely know sets don't allow duplicates). Read up on `equals()` and `hashCode()` for more information.

Comment: @Thomas actually they don't replace each other. Only the first element is added.

Comment: @Eran ah yes, you're right. I should reread the JavaDoc ("If this set already contains the element, the call leaves the set unchanged and returns false.") - d'oh.

Comment: maybe an indication that we should never disregard the value returned by `add` (and other similar methods)...

Answer (score 18):

Your defined `public boolean equals(Object f)` and `public int hashCode()` methods in the `Foo` class that basically say all `Foo` instances are equal to each other, so only one instance of `Foo` can be added to any `HashSet`.

Therefore `myFooSet.size()` will return 1, regardless of the number of `Foo` elements you attempted to add to it (as long as you added at least one).

Note: your `public boolean equals(Foo f)` method is never used by `HashSet`, since `HashSet` only uses the `equals` method declared in `Object` class - `public boolean equals(Object obj)` - which you overrode to always return `true`.

Comment: The other important detail to make explicit is the `equals(Foo)` overload is never invoked, because HashMap has no way to know that exists, so `equals(Object)` is the overload that is invoked. So whilst `new Foo(1).equals(new Foo(1))` is false, that's never actually used.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to @Eran answer, defining `equals(Foo f)` method isn't overriding the [Object.equals(java.lang.Object)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) method being used when comparing, even if your Object is `Foo`

```
public boolean equals(Foo f) {
```

Isn't called in your code